# WPF DataGrid CurrentItem is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF toolkit DataGrid that is bound to an observable collection of objects in the view model. In this DataGrid, I have defined a DataGridTemplateColumn for a certain field of that object. (Car.Name)

I'm trying to detect duplicates and set a certain style on the cell that already exists in another list of (similar) objects.

When this dialog gets loaded there is no selection. The IsDuplicate in the view model does get called for each item of the row, but I am unable to tell which item it's currently on in the view model. I thought of using CurrentItem, but it seems to always be null.

Question: How do I know in the View Model which current item is being called?

View XAML:

```
    <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
                      CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentCar}">

     ...

     <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridCell}">
         <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType=toolkit:DataGrid}, 
                        Path=DataContext.IsDuplicate}" Value="False">
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
           </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType=toolkit:DataGrid}, 
                        Path=DataContext.IsDuplicate}" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
             <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
             <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Duplicate" />
           </DataTrigger>                   
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
     </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
public Car CurrentCar { get; set; }

public bool IsDuplicate
{
  get
  {
    // Logic to check current car against a list of cars
    var x = CurrentCar; // null
   }
}
```

> | Name | ...
>
> | Car 1 | ... <-- Highlight
>
> | Car 2 | ...
>
> | Car 1 | ... <-- Highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about it the wrong way.  This shouldn't be an iterative method. `IsDuplicate` needs to be a property of `Car`, with a link to the collection so that each `Car` object determines if there are other items in the collection that match it.

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Collection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public bool IsDuplicate
    {
        get
        {
            // Logic to check current car against a list of cars
            return (Cars.Count(c => c.Id.Equals(this.Id))) > 1;
        }
    }    
}
```

Then in XAML:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridCell}">
     <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="IsDuplicate" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
       </DataTrigger>
       <DataTrigger Binding="IsDuplicate" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
         <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Duplicate" />
       </DataTrigger>                   
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
 </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

Not so sure about the XAML binding syntax, that's just off the top of my head.  But you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCar}">
```

Comment: When the dialog gets loaded, there is no selection.

Comment: @mastofact then select an item programatically. `CurrentCar = Cars.FirstOrDefault()`. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @mastofact, I'm not trying to be too presumptuous, but I think your question is actually wrong, which is why @HighCore is missing the point here.  I *think* you don't actually want to know which item is selected based on your stated goal: "I'm trying to detect duplicates and set a certain style on the cell that already exists in another list of (similar) objects." All you need for this is a property of `Car` that will accomplish this; you shouldn't be iterating through each item in any particular order.  WPF will handle the iteration for you.